# inner join en no sql (mongo)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Hola quisiera hacer un inner join en mongo y por mas que lo inetnto no sale y no se que pueda estar pasando, les colocare aca las descripciones de las tablas y lo que estoy haciendo para ver si alguien puede ayudarme:

tabla User
Campos:
_id,
nombre,
correo,
tipo

tabla Trans
campos:
_id,
user_id (guarda el id de User),
trans_des,
trans_numero,
trans_tipo

el join que quiero hacer es el siguiente:

```
select * from User
inner join Trans on Trans.user_id=User._id
where Trans.trans_tipo='bank'
```

aca les dejo mi aggregate:

```
db.getCollection("User").aggregate([
 { "$addFields": { "_id": { "$toString": "$_id" }}},
{"$lookup": {
     "from": "Trans",
     "foreignField": "user_id",
      "localField": "_id",
       "as": "Trans"
        }},
          {
            "$match": {
                "Trans.trans_tipo": "bank"
            }
          }
     
])
```

no sale la BD se queda pensando y no arroja ni error ni resultado, por fa si alguien puede ver el error de antemano gracias....

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones para hacerlo:

1. Utilizar `pipeline` en el join para no mezclar los que no sean :`tipo=bank`.
2. Hacer el join y después filtar por el valor.

Yo prefiero la opción 1, hacerlo en el join (`$lookup`) te ahorras hacer `$unwind`.

Por lo que, la query sería algo como:

- Hacer el join (`$lookup`) con una pipeline donde indicas que quieres mergear por `_id` y `trans_tipo = bank`.
- Esto genera un array `trans` en cada documento. Si está vacío es que no ha habido ninguna coincidencia, por lo que se puede filtar con `$match` donde el array no esté vacío.

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "trans",
      "let": {
        "id": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$user_id",
                    "$$id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$trans_tipo",
                    "bank"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "trans"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "trans": {
        "$ne": []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jBurtqD5jpJ)

Y para la opción2, [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FcVT8RupIlk) hay un ejemplo